# how to detect error line number using yacc parser

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

We have no idea on how to track errors in yacc parser.
We're trying to use `yylineno` in our lex file and tried adding `%option yylineno` but it's still not workin', we cannot access these variables in yacc.

All we want is to print out the syntax error using the `error` in yacc together with the line number.

here's our `.l` file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
int yylineno=1;

%}

%option yylineno

identifier  [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
int_constant    [0-9]+
delimiter       ;

%%

"int"       {return INT;}
{int_constant}  return INT_CONST;
{identifier}    return IDENT;
\=      {return ASOP;}
\+      {return PLUS;}
\-      {return MINUS;}
\*      {return MULT;}
\/      {return DIV;}
\,      {return COMMA;}
\(      {return OP;} /*OP CP = Opening Closing Parenthesis*/
\)      {return CP;}
\[      {return OB;} /*OB CB = Opening Closing Brace*/
\]      {return CB;}
\{      {return OCB;} /*OCB CCB = Opening Closing Curly Brace*/
\}      {return CCB;}
{delimiter} return DEL;
[ \t]
[\n]        {yylineno++;}


%%
```

now here's our `.y` file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

extern FILE *yyin;

%}

%token INT INT_CONST IDENT ASOP PLUS MINUS MULT DIV DEL COMMA CP CB CCB
%left OP OB OCB


%%

program:        program_unit;
program_unit:   program_unit component | component
component:  var_decl DEL | func_decl DEL | func_defn ;
var_decl:       dt list;
dt:     INT;
list:       list COMMA var | var 
        | error {printf("before ';' token\n"); yyerrok;}
        | error INT_CONST {printf("before numeric constant\n"); yyerrok;};
var:        IDENT
        |IDENT init;
init:       ASOP IDENT init | ASOP expr | ASOP IDENT ;
expr:       IDENT op expr | const op expr | const | OP expr CP;
const:      INT_CONST;
op:     PLUS | MINUS | MULT | DIV;
func_decl:  dt mult_func;
mult_func:  mult_func COMMA mfunc | sfunc;
mfunc:      IDENT OP CP;
sfunc:      IDENT OP CP OCB func_body CCB;
func_body:  program_unit;

func_defn:  dt IDENT OP CP OCB func_body CCB
        | IDENT OP CP OCB func_body CCB; 

%%

int yyerror(char *s){
    extern int yylineno;
    fprintf(stderr,"At line %d %s ",s,yylineno);  
}

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    yyin=fopen("test.c","r");
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  Otherwise we can't tell you what you have done wrong.

Comment: @Stephen C. Mister, our `.l` and `.y` files are now together with the recent post. You can also give us examples, evan the simplest one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of problems with those files, but none of them will prevent `yylineno` from being available to your bison-generated parser.

There will be a compile-time warning resulting from your definition of `yyerror`. Or possibly several warnings.

First, the correct signature is:

```
void yyerror(const char *msg);
```

It's ok to return an `int` but the value is never used; however, your definition of the function just falls off the end, so the compiler will complain about the fact that no value is returned. Also, `yyerror` is normally called with a literal string argument, which is immutable; standard C allows literal strings to be passed to a function whose parameter type is non-const, but the usage is not recommended and a compiler might warn. More importantly,

```
fprintf(stderr,"At line %d %s ",s,yylineno);
```

applies the `%d` (integer) format to `s` (a string) and the `%s` (string) format to `yylineno` (an integer); again, this should produce a compile-time warning and if you ignore the error, your program will probably segfault.

Finally (relevant to `yylineno`), if you specify `%option yylineno` in your `flex` input (which is a good idea if you want to count line numbers) then the flex-generated scanner will define and initialize `yylineno` and do the counting for you. So your definition of `yylineno` in your `.l` file will trigger a compile-time error (redefinition of `yylineno`). Also when you increment `yylineno` (`[\n] {++yylineno;}`) explicitly, you end up double-counting lines; `yylineno` will be incremented by the scanner and then incremented again by your action. My advice: specify `%option yylineno` and then let flex do everything for you. You only need to declare it as `extern` in your `bison` file (as you do). And you can just add `\n` to the list of ignored whitespace characters.

One caveat: using `yylineno` directly in `bison` means that you will not have an exact location for syntax errors, because the `bison`-generated parser has usually read one lookahead token, and `yylineno` will already have been updated to the line number at the end of this token by the time `bison` notices the syntax error. Sometimes this is misleading, especially in the case of syntax errors caused by a missing token.

Some other problems:

- It's much better style (IMHO) to use literal character tokens rather than define token names in `bison` and coordinate them with your `flex` file. If you just use literal characters, then the two files are much easier to keep in synch with each other; the grammar is more readable; and you don't need comments like

  ```
  /*OP CP = Opening Closing Parenthesis*/
  ```

  Instead, just use `')'` in the grammar, and in the lexer you can do something like this:

  ```
  [][=+*/,(){}-]  { return yytext[0]; }
  ```

  Or you could even just use a default rule at the end:

  ```
  .  { return yytext[0]; }
  ```
- Related to the above, and the reason why I usually choose the second option (the default rule), your lexer does not have a rule for all possible characters, and consequently the flex-provided default rule will be used. The flex-provided default rule is to just echo the invalid character to `yyout`. That's never what you want in an actual compiler, and the result is that input errors (or scanner bugs) are silently hidden. It's better to use a default rule like the one I suggest above and to protect yourself by using `%option nodefault` to avoid the flex-generated default rule. With `%option nodefault`, flex will give you a warning if there is any possibility that the input won't match; please don't ignore this warning.